# Checking Ontology Consistency in Run Time

Tags: protege, apache-jena, pellet

I have a program that uses Jena to load an .owl Ontology designed in Protege. I am trying to do reasoning over it using Pellet in a way that if I add some statements in run time to model be able to check its consistency. For example I have 'Method', 'Signature' and 'hasSignature' concepts in which hasSignature is an object property. I have following axiom:

```
Method hasSignature exactly 1 Signature
```

When I add some instance statements in order to violate above axiom no inconsistency is reported. Here is my code:

```
List<Statement> statements = new ArrayList<>();

OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF);
FileManager.get().readModel(model, "Ontologies\\Ontology.owl");

OntClass Method = model.createClass( ns + "Method");
Individual method1 = Method.createIndividual(ns + "method1");

OntClass Signature = model.createClass( ns + "Signature");
Individual sign1 = Signature.createIndividual(ns + "sign1");
Individual sign2 = Signature.createIndividual(ns + "sign2");

Property hasSignature = model.createObjectProperty(ns + "hasSignature");

Statement st = model.createStatement(method1, hasSignature, sign1);
statements.add(st);

Statement st1 = model.createStatement(method1, hasSignature, sign2);
statements.add(st1);

Reasoner reasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.theInstance().create();
InfModel inf = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, model.add(statements));
System.out.println(inf.validate().isValid());
```

What's wrong? Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared `sign1` and `sign2` to be different from each other. So, since it is possible for the two individuals to be `sameAs` each other, the reasoner has determined that that's the only case not rising a clash. Therefore the ontology is consistent.